# Can you tell me what is that button for? Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 - gnome classic

Tags: gnome, indicator, panel

I'm just switching to ubuntu gnome, starting with linux few months ago. Can you just tell me what is that button for? Next one to settings and lock...

[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try it? I have no idea, but it looks like screen rotation lock or something like that to me. Are you on a notebook/tablet/...?

Comment: Of course I did a try before I've asked :) nothing what I could noticed. On notebook.

Comment: Well... That's it! I didn't know I have notebook with some rotation sensor. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool. I posted that as an answer, so that you can accept it by clicking the grey round check button on its left to mark your question as solved. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I correctly guessed and you confirmed in your comment, that button locks the screen orientation.

Looks like your notebook has a rotation sensor and could therefore automatically rotate the screen when the device is rotated, so that the upper side is always up.

The button is there to lock the orientation or to activate automatic rotating.